# Getting "Field data loading is forbidden" when trying to aggregate

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to do a simple unique aggregation, but getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Field data loading is forbidden on eid
```

this is my query:

```
POST /logstash-2016.06.*/Nginx/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter":  [
          {
            "term": { 
              "pid": "1"
            }
          },
          {
            "term": { 
              "cvprogress": "0"
            }
          },
          {
          "range" : {
              "ServerTime" : {
                  "gte" : "2016-06-28T00:00:00"
              }
          }
          }
      ]
    }
  },
    "aggs": {
          "distinct_colors" : {
              "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "eid"
              }
          }
        }

}
```

Comment: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15267

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After going through the entire thread at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/15267 what worked was adding .raw

like this:

```
"aggs": {
          "distinct_colors" : {
              "cardinality" : {
                "field" : "eid.raw"
              }
          }
        }
```